# Nokogiri for Ruby on WindowsXP: 6 hours of my life gone

Tags: ruby, installation, nokogiri, libxml2

I just want to install Nokogiri for Ruby on my Windows XP.  The process is apparently so obfuscated and divergent that I have about 50 different tabs and windows open trying to install Libxml, devKit, other versions of what I already have, and so on.  Does anybody know the secrets of how to install Nokogiri for Ruby on Windows?

Configuration

On my Windows XP, Version 2002 SP3, I have the following directories:

- List item
- C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3
- C:\Ruby200
- C:\libxml2-2.9.1
- C:\DevKit
- C:\Python27
- C:\Python33

Both ruby's are installed, I have no idea about the DevKit or the libxml. The libxml2-2.9.1 is some kind of python source, so I thought it would be a great idea to install python, which I know nothing about, and try to compile it; hence the two python folders.

I have

libxml-ruby 2.6.0 [rdoc] [www] - depends on hanna_guado.
    Ruby Bindings for LibXML2

libxslt-ruby 1.1.0 [rdoc] [www] - depends on libxml-ruby.
    Ruby libxslt bindings

installed on ruby, but when I go to do a "gem install nokogiri" it still gives me a

> ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb checking for libxml/parser.h... no
> ```
>
> ----- libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with
>   installing dependencies.

Comment: What version of Nokogiri?

Comment: I was just doing gem install nokogiri, so I assume it would get the latest. Bitnami worked, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend looking into the Bitnami one-click Ruby installers. They *might* work with XP.

Otherwise I'd try running a VM with a small Linux guest system. It would be a lot less pain.

Windows isn't exactly friendly to open-source languages and yours is pretty old. Finding the individual components installed is hard enough without a full installer on a current version of the OS, on an old one it's harder and becomes like herding cats.

OS languages fit Linux nicely, and work pretty well with Mac OS because it's *nix based.

Those are the things I'd try instead of what you are doing.

http://bitnami.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips! I'll give them a try.

Comment: Still downloading the ruby stack from bitnami; it says it already has Nokogiri, so my fingures are crossed.  I do think I should set up a VM with Linux eventually anyways.  Meanwhile, I found a pretty good video about herding cats: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pk7yqlTMvp8